# DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown when saving twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I save an entity object for the first time, it works perfectly, but on the second attempt on the same object, it fails with a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.
I've set the `Concurrency Mode` to `Fixed` on the "LastUpdated" property, which is a DateTime and there is only one instance of the Context that is maintained as long as the application is running.

Before saving my objects I automatically update the "concurrency" (DatMaj) property, here is my save method (this is a simplified version, but it still crashes) :

```
    public virtual bool Save(IDbEntity pEntityToSave)
    {
        pEntityToSave.DatMaj = DateTime.Now;
        var result = ContextManager.Context.SaveChanges();

        //With this the DbUpdateConcurrencyException problem disappears, but it is a unnecessary hit to the database.
        //if (result > 0)
        //    Reload(pEntityToSave);

        return (result > 0);
    }
```

It works pretty well on the first time.
But if I edit it and save it again a few seconds later, `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown.

What is really strange is that if I log the SQL generated by Entity Framework, on the second attempt, I see:

```
UPDATE [flux].[EXO_PTN_Partenaire]
SET [PTN_DatMaj] = @0
WHERE (([PTN_IdPartenaire] = @1) AND ([PTN_DatMaj] = @2))

-- @0: '17/12/2013 18:04:20' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @1: '2' (Type = Int64)

-- @2: '17/12/2013 18:04:03' (Type = DateTime2)

-- Executing at 17/12/2013 18:04:20 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: 0
```

As you can see, it says `Completed in 1 ms with result: 0` but if I execute the exact same query manually directly on the database, it works.

And if in the `try...catch...` I call `ex.Entries.Single().Reload();` and save again, it works and logs a SQL query with **exactly** the same filters.
I don't know why it doesn't seem to be able to execute that (I suspect that it doesn't really execute it), while I can do it.
Did I miss something ? Is it a kind of cache issue ? I thought that Entity Framework was resetting the object status (State, Original values...) after saving but maybe not entirely.

A simple workaround that fixes the issue is to use `Reload()` just after `SaveChanges()` but I feel that it is a useless hit to the database. Is there another workaround ?

I'm using C# 4.0 (WPF), with Entity Framework 6 (DbContext), on an SQL Server 2008 R2 database

**Update : as requested, the stacktrace**

```
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>PS.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ...DS.BaseDS`1.Save(IDbEntity pEntityToSave) in ...:line 38
   at ...BS.BaseBS`1.Save(TEntity pEntity) in ...:line 26
   at ...PS.ViewModel.BaseViewModel`2.SaveCurrentEntity() in ...:line 129
   at ...PS.ViewModel.FileViewModel.Enregistrer_Execute() in...:line 69
   at ...PS.ViewModel.FileViewModel.&amp;lt;InitializeCommands&amp;gt;b__6(Object x) in ...:line 51
   at ...WPF.DelegateCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in ...:line 84
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ...PS.App.Main() in ...:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. ---&amp;gt; System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.&amp;lt;Update&amp;gt;b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;SaveChangesToStore&amp;gt;b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass9.&amp;lt;SaveChanges&amp;gt;b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ...DS.BaseDS`1.Save(IDbEntity pEntityToSave) in ...:line 38
   at ...BS.BaseBS`1.Save(TEntity pEntity) in ...:line 26
   at ...PS.ViewModel.BaseViewModel`2.SaveCurrentEntity() in ...:line 129
   at ...PS.ViewModel.FileViewModel.Enregistrer_Execute() in ...:line 69
   at ...PS.ViewModel.FileViewModel.&amp;lt;InitializeCommands&amp;gt;b__6(Object x) in ...:line 51
   at ...WPF.DelegateCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in...:line 84
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ...PS.App.Main() in ...:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><DataItems><Data></Data></DataItems><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.&amp;lt;Update&amp;gt;b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;SaveChangesToStore&amp;gt;b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass9.&amp;lt;SaveChanges&amp;gt;b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.&amp;lt;Update&amp;gt;b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;SaveChangesToStore&amp;gt;b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass9.&amp;lt;SaveChanges&amp;gt;b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but if you add it to modifiesEntities twice:

```
if (pEntityToUpdate != null)
    modifiedEntities.Add(pEntityToUpdate);
```

..I would expect some problems. It looks like that 'if' should be testing something else. Does the entity have an IDENITY column? If so, the test should be against that being set.

Cheers -

Comment: modifiedEntities is just a temp variable in order to apply the date changes. The item is not added twice to that list.
The method takes one entity or none. If one entity, it means I want to force this item to be updated (so even if the user didn't change anything, I want it to be marked as modified, which will happen if I change the date), if none, all the entity that will be saved must be updated. To be sure, I tried removing this code, keeping only the date update, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: OK, I see that now. Since the SQL is generating OK, then it's something in the EF which is getting upset when it adjusts internal state after the SQL finishes. Reloading the entity fixes it and the save then works, yes? Just a guess, but it might be worth getting the Entity Model to regenerate the code

Comment: Yes, reloading works. So this is not a critical issue, it's just annoying to reload the exact same data I just saved. It's an unnecessary query. And I regenerate the code often as I'm working on the schema, issue always there :(.

Comment: Let's step back a second. What's the list of modified entities for? Also, you say it runs OK the first time, but after: is the first time when you create the object?

Comment: No. Both are updates. I pasted here the code I use to update the property just before SaveChanges, in case I do something wrong. But my saving method could be simplified to something like `public void Save(IDbEntity pEntity) { pEntity.DatMaj = DateTime.Now; ContextManager.Context.SaveChanges(); }` and the problem remains the same.   
If I add `ContextManager.Context.Entry(pEntity).Reload();` after `SaveChanges()`, it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, Julian, but I have to give up here. I've never seen anything like this and can't find anything on the Web at all. The codeplex site says to post here as you've done. Lets hope some of the EF Devs can shed some light on it. One final thing, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: No problem, I'll update with the simpler version of Save() in order to prevent the confusion my current method generates, and add the stacktrace.